# Pop Up page that is not part of tabs (Xamarin forms)

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have 4 tabs on my app. One of the tabs, Me tab, when onclick should pop up the login page when user is not logged in. How do I do this on xamarin forms? I've been doing all sorts of research on it but nothing seems to work for me.

```
    if (login == false)
        {
            var me = new NavigationPage(new UserLogin());
            me.Icon = "Icon/icon_me1.png";
            //navigationPage.Title = "Me";
            Children.Add(me);
            Device.OnPlatform(iOS: () => me.Title = "Me");
        }
        else if (login == true) 
        {
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
            var me = new NavigationPage(new Me());
            me.Icon = "Icon/icon_me1.png"; 

            Children.Add(me);
            Device.OnPlatform(iOS: () => me.Title = "Me");
        }
```

Comment: Have you wrapped your `Page` in a `NavigationPage`? Then just push a new Page as Modal.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis I'm rather confused. I currently have this code (added in qn)

Comment: Check out [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/introduction-to-xamarin-forms/#Modal_Navigation) piece in the documentation. Add `Navigation.PushAsync(new Me());` instead on the code you have now in `login == true`.

Comment: When i do as told, the login page is still part of the tabs instead of pop up. After login, the Me page stand on it's own with no tabs. and when clicked back, instead of having 4 tabs it became 3 @GeraldVersluis